Handle internet connection errors while running bot with bot.run()
What is a proper way to handle internet connection errors while running a Discord bot with bot.run()?
from discord.ext import commands

token = "my_token"
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='%', intents=intents)

bot.run(token)

When internet connection is off this bot just shuts down completely due to an error. I can not put my bot.run() call into a loop, so it will be closed completely on every such error. There are some answers about looping client.run() but they are no good for bot.run().

Looks like there's an easy built-in way to handle this.
reconnect=True should do the trick, so the last line in my example must be
bot.run(token, reconnect=True)

As the user manual says:

[we can use it] if we should attempt reconnecting, either due to internet failure or a specific failure on Discord’s part. Certain disconnects that lead to bad state will not be handled (such as invalid sharding payloads or bad tokens).

